# Pythonic way of iterating over ranges when order is not known

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

Say I have 2 variables `x` and `y` and I want to iterate over all the values in between without knowing whether `x` or `y` is greater:

```
if(x>y):
  for i in range(y,x):
    #Code

elif(x<y):
  for i in range(x,y):
    #Code
```

What is the Pythonic way to do this without all the `if-else` conditions? The order does not matter descending or ascending will do, but a general answer would be great!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about:

```
for i in range(min(x,y), max(x,y)):
    ...
```

Answer (score 5):

Another way is to use `sorted` with [unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/):

```
x, y = 10, 1
for i in range(*sorted([x,y])):
    print(i)
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
...
```

Answer (score 4):

How about sorting them beforehand?

```py
smaller, larger = sorted((a,b))
for elem in range(smaller, larger):
    # ...
```

or shorter:

```py
for elem in range(*sorted((a,b))):
    # ...
```

Comment: I like the descriptive variable names.

Answer (score 3):

You can check the `max` and `min`:

```
def custom_range(x, y):
    M, m = max(x, y), min(x, y)
    yield from xrange(m, M) # or range in python3
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use `min` and `max` :

```py
for i in range( min(x,y), max(x,y) ):
    ...
```